# Delete some subsets of a dataframe, and modify other subsets

Tags: r, dataframe

NOTE: modified with a sample data frame to improve readability.

Suppose I have the following dataframe `df`

```
    GRID FLOW NITER    tau    eta    psi
67     0   87 66001 0.6571 0.9050 0.5947
68     0   87 67001 0.6571 0.9050 0.5947
69     0   87 68001 0.6571 0.9050 0.5947
70     0   87 69001 0.6572 0.9050 0.5947
71     0   87 70001 0.6571 0.9050 0.5947
72     0   87 71001 0.6572 0.9050 0.5947
73     0   87 72001 0.6571 0.9050 0.5947
74     0   87 73001 0.6571 0.9050 0.5947
75     0   87 74001 0.6571 0.9050 0.5947
207    1   87 66001 0.6539 0.9001 0.5886
208    1   87 67001 0.6539 0.9001 0.5886
209    1   87 68001 0.6539 0.9001 0.5886
210    1   87 69001 0.6539 0.9001 0.5886
277    2   87 66001 0.6573 0.9031 0.5935
278    2   87 67001 0.6573 0.9031 0.5935
279    2   87 68001 0.6573 0.9031 0.5935
280    2   87 69001 0.6573 0.9031 0.5935
347    3   87 66001 0.6575 0.9020 0.5930
348    3   87 67001 0.6575 0.9020 0.5930
349    3   87 68001 0.6575 0.9020 0.5930
350    3   87 69001 0.6575 0.9020 0.5930
627    7   87 66001 0.6573 0.9020 0.5929
628    7   87 67001 0.6573 0.9020 0.5929
629    7   87 68001 0.6573 0.9020 0.5929
630    7   87 69001 0.6573 0.9021 0.5929
631    7   87 70001 0.6573 0.9021 0.5929
632    7   87 71001 0.6573 0.9021 0.5929
633    7   87 72001 0.6573 0.9021 0.5929
634    7   87 73001 0.6573 0.9021 0.5929
635    7   87 74001 0.6573 0.9021 0.5929
```

The `GRID` variable and the `NITER` variable are integers. As you can see, for some values of `GRID` (1, 2 and 3 in this example), the maximum value of `NITER` is 69001. For other values of `GRID` (0 and 7 in this example), the maximum `NITER` is above 69001. For all such groups, I need to eliminate the observations with `NITER`< 69001, and subtract 70000 to the `NITER` values of the other observations. I could do this with a `for` loop, but loops are slow in R, thus I'd prefer a more R-style solution.

Comment: Assuming you can distinguish groups using another variable `GRID`, (i.e. `GRID` is unique). `dplyr` should do the trick. You can then `group_by(grid) %>% mutate(itermax=max(NITER))` etc and go from there. No looping required.

Comment: It would have been better if you make a small example with 10 to 15 rows and expected output.

Comment: @intra, thanks a lot for the suggestion. I installed this `dplyr` package you're referring to, and `require`ed it. I got some warning messages, hopefully not important. However, I don't know the commands you use. I tried executing your instruction but it doesn't work (I guess because  `df` is not referenced). Could you please elaborate a bit in an answer? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr` uses chaining for readability. You should find the syntax pretty usable if you're used to SQL at all.

Good manual too: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html

Because I'm only guessing at the structure of your data, I can only pseudo-code a response. Again, this will only work if grouping by `GRID` gives you some idea of the 'clumps' of NITER you're trying to adjust.

```
df1 <- df %>% 
       group_by(GRID) %>% 
       mutate(itermax=max(NITER),
              NNITER=ifelse(itermax>69001L, NITER-70000L, NITER),
              keep=NNITER > 0) %>%
       filter(keep) %>%
       select(GRID, FLOW, NNITER, tau, eta, psi)


> as.data.frame(df1)
   GRID FLOW NNITER    tau    eta    psi
1     0   87      1 0.6571 0.9050 0.5947
2     0   87   1001 0.6572 0.9050 0.5947
3     0   87   2001 0.6571 0.9050 0.5947
4     0   87   3001 0.6571 0.9050 0.5947
5     0   87   4001 0.6571 0.9050 0.5947
6     1   87  66001 0.6539 0.9001 0.5886
7     1   87  67001 0.6539 0.9001 0.5886
8     1   87  68001 0.6539 0.9001 0.5886
9     1   87  69001 0.6539 0.9001 0.5886
10    2   87  66001 0.6573 0.9031 0.5935
11    2   87  67001 0.6573 0.9031 0.5935
12    2   87  68001 0.6573 0.9031 0.5935
13    2   87  69001 0.6573 0.9031 0.5935
14    3   87  66001 0.6575 0.9020 0.5930
15    3   87  67001 0.6575 0.9020 0.5930
16    3   87  68001 0.6575 0.9020 0.5930
17    3   87  69001 0.6575 0.9020 0.5930
18    7   87      1 0.6573 0.9021 0.5929
19    7   87   1001 0.6573 0.9021 0.5929
20    7   87   2001 0.6573 0.9021 0.5929
21    7   87   3001 0.6573 0.9021 0.5929
22    7   87   4001 0.6573 0.9021 0.5929
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I don't know what is SQL. I'm not sure if I'll be able to do it today, but by tomorrow at latest I will update the question with a sample `df`, smaller than the actual ones but with a similar structure. By the way, yes, grouping by `GRID` effectively separates between different "clumps" of `NITER`.

Comment: I managed to add a sample `df` to my question. I tried to run your instruction, but I got the following error: `Error: incompatible types, expecting a numeric vector
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (c(69001L, 69001L, 69001L, 69001L, 74001L, 74001L, 74001L,  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (c(69001L, 69001L, 69001L, 69001L, 74001L, 74001L, 74001L,  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: Fixed. Must use `ifelse` with `dplyr`. Guess we all learn something!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a bunch :)